# What are `dd` input blocks?

Tags: encryption, linux, disk-encryption, file-encryption, decryption

I'm looking for a semi-technical explanation of "input blocks". When [creating encrypted containers](https://willhaley.com/blog/encrypted-file-container-disk-image-in-linux/) we use [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) with "count=n", but I'm not sure of the difference between "count=0" and "count=1". The `dd` manpage simply states:

```
   count=N
          copy only N input blocks
```

What are input blocks?

Comment: It's an arbitrary size block set by `bs` or `ibs`. It's also not related to security, what you're using it for doesn't really affect your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block size that `dd` will process `count` of is determined by the `bs` (`ibs`, `obs`) argument to `dd`:

```
bs=BYTES
      read and write up to BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512);
      overrides ibs and obs
```

That's per this new [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html); back when I learned on [SunOS 4](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54764/dd-1m.html) it was more clear that "bs" stood for "block size":

```
bs=n
   Sets both input and output block sizes to n bytes, superseding ibs= and obs=. If 
   no conversion other than sync,noerror , and notrunc is specified, each input 
   block is copied to the output as a single block without aggregating short blocks.
```

And as you can see in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259208/purpose-of-find-commands-default-size-unit-512-bytes) early versions of Unix used a 512 byte "block", or unit of allocation, in filesystems.  That's why the current default for `dd` `bs` is still 512 bytes!

You can also specify other size units; for example, `bs=5M` to have a block size of 5 Megabytes:

```
N and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes:
c =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024,
xM =M, GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E,
Z, Y.
```

In your case, no matter what the `bs` is set to, if you choose `count=0` you won't write anything!  If you leave `bs` unset and choose `count=1`, you'll write 512 bytes.

This strict control over "block size" makes much more sense when you're dealing with tapes or other sequential, limited devices.  If you write 128k blocks of data to a tape drive with 64k block size, you just lost half your data!  Writing to a file(system), unlike an actual device, is far more forgiving about allocating space for whatever you want to give it.